# Sort folders first, then files [El Capitan]

Tags: terminal, finder, macos, sort

I am aware there are many posts about this problem, but many are just workarounds for Finder. However I use console more often then Finder because of programming.

I am also aware of something like this (after getting coreutils):

`alias ll='gls -la -h --group-directories-first'`

But thats just another 'plugin' or external utility, which does the job well but doesn't answer my question.

I also found out that Dropbox web also sorts your files according to the User Agent. If it is changed from the Develop menu in Safari to IE or Firefox/Chrome (Widows) then it sorts folders first.

I get that OS X and Windows must be rebels so they use different sorting but frankly it's a mess when you got plenty files and they all get mixed up.

Does OS X have a system wide setting for this so when I type `ls -la` output is sorted folders first then files and both are alphabetically ascending (a to z)? Or is the sorting mechanism related to the implementation of program/application which is displaying files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I've tried to put a clear question at the end of the post. Ca you edit this if I somehow missed your main point?

Comment: Does `alias ls='ls -laO | grep "^d" && ls -laO | grep "^-" && ls -laO | grep "^l"'` meet your requirements in Terminal?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300615/group-directories-first-option-for-ls-command

Comment: If you're still bothered by this, remember that the macOS command line is open source. Eventually someone will be bugged enough to scratch that itch. ;-) https://github.com/torstenvl/betterls

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer is no, if the question is whether the native `ls` command can be configured to list directories before it lists non-directories. One of the comments suggests a shell pipeline, but rather than going to that trouble it might be easier to write a script.

The following python code is by no means intended to be a complete substitute for the `ls` command, but complicating it to handle more of what `ls` provides feels doable (python's `argparse` module would help with that).

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                    

import os
import sys

for top in sys.argv[1:]:
    for (name, dirs, files) in os.walk(top):
        print("{}:".format(name))
        for dir in dirs:
            print("{}/".format(dir))
        for file in files:
            print(file)
```

What makes the separation of directories from non-directories easy in this example is that python's `os.walk` does that for me, in its return value. The use of `os.walk` implicitly imposes the equivalent of `ls -R`, but that should be easy to fix by adapting code from `os.walk`, which is native python code built on top of `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir`, rather than invoking `os.walk` directly.

With respect to the question of native capabilities versus external utilities, python is native to recent releases of `MacOS`. Where scripting like this ranks compared to pulling in external functionality is a matter of taste.

There might be an invocation of `find` which fits your criteria, similar to the `ls` pipeline in a comment, using the `-type` option in multiple invocations of `find`, but to me that feels clumsy compared to python code.