# --group-directories-first option for "ls" command

Tags: macos, bash

I am using both Ubuntu 16.04 and OS X.

```
alias ll='ls -Flh --group-directories-first'
```

This is an alias in my bashrc, but somehow `--group-directories-first` option got illegal in OS X after I upgraded my bash with Homebrew. In my Ubuntu desktop, I still can use that option.

In what version of Bash, the option is unsupported? The Bash version in my OS X machine says `GNU bash, Version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)`

I would like to use `--group-directories-first` option again. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Are you using the gnu correutils `ls` or the macOS `ls` ? Have you tried the other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Install `coreutils` with Homebrew and alias `ll` to `gls -Flh --group-directories-first` instead.

- `brew install coreutils` [installs GNU Coreutils](https://superuser.com/a/109546/105707), in case it is not installed.
- Use `alias ll='gls -Flh --group-directories-first'` in `.bashrc`.
  (If you want to use the same `.bashrc` file in both operating systems, see below.)

In Ubuntu, [`ls` is provided by GNU Coreutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/coreutils/filelist), which Ubuntu always has. That's why `ls` supports `--group-directories-first` in Ubuntu. Probably you had been using the GNU Coreutils version of `ls` on macOS before, too, which Homebrew installs as `gls` but which can be made usable as `ls` in several ways.

[**`ls` is an external command, not a Bash builtin.**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) Using a different version or build of Bash should not affect it. I'm not sure what happened when you upgraded Bash using Homebrew. Maybe more than Bash got upgraded too; maybe you had an `ls` shell function or alias defined in a global configuration file that was replaced; maybe you had a symbolic link `ls` that had pointed to `gls` and was overwritten; maybe you still have something like that but your `$PATH` has changed. Whatever happened, [GNU Coreutils `ls` supports `--group-directories-first`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Which-files-are-listed), and switching to it (as I believe [**bmike is suggesting**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300615/group-directories-first-option-for-ls-command#comment379736_300615)) should fix your problem.

If for some reason you want to use the exact same `.bashrc` file in both systems, there are a few possible approaches. You could create a symlink, wrapper script, shell function, or (because Bash alias expansion is nonrecursive) shell alias for `gls` in your Ubuntu system. But I suggest instead [checking which OS is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394235/1038860) in `.bashrc`. Although you will get a different `ll` alias defined in each system, this approach has the benefit of being self-documenting. Your `.bashrc` will make sense to you in a year, or a month.

```bash
if [ "$OSTYPE" == linux-gnu ]; then  # Is this the Ubuntu system?
    alias ll='ls -Flh --group-directories-first'
else
    alias ll='gls -Flh --group-directories-first'
fi
```

Or if you find you usually prefer to run the Coreutils `ls`, even if you're not using the `ll` alias, you can make `ls` an alias to `gls`:

```bash
if [ "$OSTYPE" != linux-gnu ]; then  # Is this the macOS system?
    alias ls=gls
fi

alias ll='ls -Flh --group-directories-first'
```

(Thanks go to [soroushjp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/326986/soroushjp) for [catching a mistake](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300615/group-directories-first-option-for-ls-command/300623#comment469206_300623) in an earlier version of that script.)

Comment: I followed this answer and use:
alias ls='gls --color -h --group-directories-first'
alias ll='ls -al'

Comment: I think in your last section _"Or if you find you usually prefer to run..."_, the conditional needs to be changed to:

 `"$OSTYPE" != linux-gnu`

, since you want to alias _ls_ to _gls_ if you're _not_ on a Linux GNU system (e.g. you're on a Mac).

Comment: @soroushjp Thanks--you're right. (I've fixed it; sorry about the wait!)

Comment: The problem with the GNU `ls` command is that in exchange for the `--group-directories-first` option, you lose `-O` and `-@`, which you need to list extended attributes and alternate data streams.

Comment: @Bachsau You're right. And it bugged me enough that I decided to do something about it. Since Darwin is open source it wasn't too hard to recompile it with support for the `--group-directories-first` flag. https://github.com/torstenvl/betterls